# cannot run mysqld on fedora 36 after enabling the service with systemctl

Tags: mysql, mariadb, fedora

I am not able to run mysqld, the socket connects without problem but there are some issue creating configurations files:

```
joy@fedora /]$ mysqld
2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.16-MariaDB) starting as process 4650 ...

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/fedora.lower-test

mysqld: Can't create file '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log' (errno: 13 "Permission denied")

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.

2022-11-12 12:38:24 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

When running with superuser:

```
[joy@fedora /]$ sudo mysqld

2022-11-12 12:41:13 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.16-MariaDB) starting as process 4679 ...

mysqld: Please consult the Knowledge Base to find out how to run mysqld as root!

2022-11-12 12:41:13 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

the problema was solved connecting as root with the command `mariadb -u root`